Laundry Hoses Behind Cabinet
I am planning to install a row of base cabinets next to my stacked   W/D and need a way to route the washer hoses within or behind the cabinets. Photo of setup attached. Edits to make this question more specific.
How do I deal with the washer hoses where I want base cabinets and make this look good?
Some details:

I am using Ikea Sektion base cabinets, which have a flat metal bar that goes across the top of the back of the cabinets.
The bottom of the valve box is 34 inches from the ground. I plan for the top of the cabinet counter to be flush with the bottom of the valve box.
The appliance store installed the hoses in the photo. They can be changed.
I chose not to move the valve box because we are trying a stacked W/D setup, could go back to side by side in the future, and I didn't want to spend $1k to move the valve box 2 feet.
A covered litter box is going in the base cabinet next to the W/D.
I would like 100% access to the valve box and ability to inspect/change out hoses

Any help appreciated. Thanks!


Your question is a bit nebulous. We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Hoses do like to be bent in tight quarters.  You might want to add elbows to the valves so the hoses can be straighter.

I'll try to edit this to make my question more specific. It's more of - how do I add a base cabinet here and make it look nice?

A lot of it depends on the height of the cabinets and how high the valve box is. Detailed measurements would be very helpful

Hi DJ, cabinet counter will be flush with bottom of the valve box. This will make the cabinets about 34 inches tall.

You put in your cabinet, which you say will be below the bottom of the box.  Then you build a chase out of plywood or something, and set it on top of the counter to cover the hoses.  The chase needs to be easily removed so you can access the plug and hoses/valves.
